# Add widget on mouse pressed in gui - kivy python

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy, touch, mouse

I have problem with adding and showing image to the layout every time I press the screen using mouse.

```py
class Myszka(ClickAndGo, Widget):

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        super().build()
        flaga_path = os.path.join(self.img_path, "test.png")
        x, y = touch.pos
        self.flaga = Image(source=flaga_path, size_hint=(None, None), size=(64, 64),
                           pos=(round(x, 1), round(y, 1)))
        self.camlayout.add_widget(self.flaga)
        print(touch.pos)
```

- Actual results:
  only touch position is printed, image has not been shown.
- Expected results:
  Image should have been shown, every time mouse down.

Comment: What is the inheritance / widget for `ClickAndGo`?

Comment: Is `camlayout` a class attribute of type, `Objectproperty`?

Comment: @ikolim ```self.camlayout = FloatLayout(size=(100, 100))``` and ClickAndGo inherits from ```app``` - ```class ClickAndGo(App)```

Comment: Please provide [minimal and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: @ikolim see my anwser bellow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Problem

> I have problem with adding and showing image to the layout every time
>   I press the screen using mouse.

## Root Cause

The image is not showing because it is adding to a local attribute, `self.camlayout` in method `on_touch_down()`of `class Myszka()`.

## Solution

Replace `self.camlayout.add_widget(self.flaga)` with `App.get_running_app().root.add_widget(self.flaga)` i.e. get an instance of the root (`camlayout`).

### Snippets - py

```
class Myszka(Widget):

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        ...
        App.get_running_app().root.add_widget(self.flaga)
```

## Example

The following example illustrates adding `Image` at the position of the mouse click on a `FloatLayout`.

### main.py

```
import os
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image


class Mouse(FloatLayout):

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        img_path = "/home/iam/Pictures/AppImages"
        flag_path = os.path.join(img_path, "Android_celebrate.png")
        flag = Image(source=flag_path, size_hint=(None, None), size=(64, 64),
                     pos=(round(touch.pos[0], 1), round(touch.pos[1], 1)))
        self.add_widget(flag)


class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Mouse()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

## Output

[image: Result]

Comment: damn, so greatfull bro. Cheers <33

Answer (score 0):

@ikolim

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout


class ClickAndGo(App):
    def build(self):
        self.camlayout = FloatLayout(size=(100,100))
        self.myszka = Myszka()

        self.camlayout.add_widget(self.myszka)

        return self.camlayout

class Myszka(ClickAndGo, Widget):

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        super().build()
        # test.png -> any image
        flaga_path = os.path.join(self.img_path, "test.png")
        x, y = touch.pos
        self.flaga = Image(source=flaga_path, size_hint=(None, None), size=(64, 64),
                           pos=(round(x, 1), round(y, 1)))
        self.camlayout.add_widget(self.flaga)
        print(touch.pos)
```

Comment: And every time I clicked mouse I would like to show image on position based on touch.pos